# Off-campus job and Internet earning

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas

As far as I know, international students can't work off-campus in the USA (according to the law). What about Google AdSense?

I have been working on my personal websites and I have activated AdSense on these websites. I have been getting paid in my native country (bank acount address is in my local address)and Google sends the payment to my local bank account.

Could I link my US bank account after I reach there? Will it be considered as off-campus job?

If I'm not allowed to get the money in the USA, I want to get that continuously in my native country as I'm recieveing right now.

Answer (score 2):

> Could I link my US bank account after I reach there?

Yes.

> Will it be considered as off-campus job?

Yes. As long as you do anything on these sites - you're doing work. If you don't touch them **at all**, not even maintenance - then it would not be considered work.

> If I'm not allowed to get the money in the USA, I want to get that continuously in my native country as I'm recieveing right now.

Where you get paid - doesn't matter. It's where you're doing the work that counts.